# Why is the grid View only updated on second function call?

Tags: c#, events, gridview, ext.net

i have following direct event Handler in Code-Behind:

```
public void changeBlock(string blockname)
{
  IntraNetEntities ent = new IntraNetEntities();
  var query = from x in ent.Mailings_blocked where x.blocked == blockname select x;
  if (query.Count() == 0)
  {
     Mailings_blocked add = new Mailings_blocked();
     add.blocked = blockname;
     ent.AddToMailings_blocked(add);
  }
  else
  {
     Mailings_blocked del = ent.Mailings_blocked.Single(c => c.blocked == blockname);
     ent.DeleteObject(del);
  }
  ent.SaveChanges();
  updateStore();
  Grid_Business.RefreshView();
  Grid_Mailing.RefreshView();
}
```

But when the Event is Triggered, the database gets updated, just like the store, but the RefreshView() is not correctly executed. when clicking any other Button for the same utility (this is a rowCommand) the view gets updated to desired state of one click earlier.

Comment: Is this an ASP.Net app? If so, do you have AutoPostBack set to true on the Button? I suspect this isn't ASP.Net, so have you tried to walk through the code in the debugger to see if anything untoward happens?

Comment: as tagged this is an ext.net app. i have been walking through the code multiple times, the results in self are as expected. i found the error in RefreshView(). this function fails to do as it says ;) also the grid directly listens to the store.data.changerecord event--> there is no need to call that function at all :( in the end i added `Grid_Mailing.reload(); Grid_Business.reload();` to the "After" handler. that fixed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i did not find out why, but i found out how to fix:

```
<DirectEvents>
   <Command OnEvent="GridCommand" Success="GridID.reload(); GridID.render();">
</DirectEvents>
```

Calling the reload and render to after will not necessarily help, if the response time is high, because then after gets fired before success